# Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.ScrollView' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'. Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When I run my app on Adnroid Simulator I not have a problem.
When I try to run the app on Android Phone I receive error message:

```
System.InvalidCastException 

Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Widget.ScrollView' to type 'AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar'.
```

The debugger stop here:

```
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This is my **MainActivity.cs** file in Android Project:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;

namespace SmartCryptoWorld.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SmartCryptoWorld", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

I copy this part of code:

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

From another project and I don't know if I really need it. I also copied the folder layout under resources with this files.

**Toolbar.axml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**Tabbar.axml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

**Main.axml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
</LinearLayout>
```

What Can I do tho fix this error ?

Comment: Since you are using the latest Xamarin Forms Activity which uses AndroidX, you need to convert your Layouts into AndroidX ones, such replace <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/> with <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar/> in XML layout.`

Comment: Can you show where you use the scrollview? In addition, you can check the Android version between the simulator and the phone. And I run the code on my simaulator, the toolbar doesn't show. Do you really need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the latest Xamarin Forms Activity which uses AndroidX, you need to convert your legacy libraries into AndroidX ones.

For example, replace <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/> with <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar/> in the XML layout.

And convert android.support.design.widget.TabLayout to com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout